# serial output not display in tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, pyfirmata

```
from cgitb import text

from distutils.cmd import Command

import tkinter as tk

from socket import timeout

import time

import pyfirmata

import time

from time import sleep, strftime

from tkinter import Tk, Label

from tkinter import Tk, Label

import random

import os 

import tkinter.font as tkFont

ports="COM4"

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM4')  

analog_pin0 = board.get_pin('a:1:i') 

x=0

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)  

it.start()

pin=4

analog_pin0.enable_reporting() 

board.digital[7].write(0)

voltage0 = "" 



def main():
   print("this is maoin")



def on():
      global voltage0
      root = tk.Tk()
      root.geometry("600x500")
 

      w = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
      w.pack(pady=20)  
      # B = tk.Button(root, text ="Hello", command = main) 
      # B.pack()
      w.config(text=voltage0)
      w['text'] = "intial voltage"

      B = tk.Button(root, text ="Hello", command = main)
      B.pack() 
      root.mainloop()  

      def main ():
         while True:
     
            global voltage0
            reading0 = analog_pin0.read()
            if reading0 != None:
               voltage0 = reading0 * 22.3
               voltage0 = round(voltage0,2)
               time.sleep(0.1)
               print(voltage0)
               w.config(text=voltage0)
               w['text'] = voltage0
               
               
            else:
               voltage0 = float('nan')
            
            
            
            
            string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
                  
            
            
            if (voltage0>7.3):
               time.sleep(0.1)  
               board.digital[pin].write(1)
               board.digital[6].write(0) 
               
            if(voltage0<6.5):
                  time.sleep(0.1)  
                  board.digital[pin].write(0)
                  board.digital[6].write(1) 

            

            if (voltage0==7.3):
               
               
               print()
               print(voltage0)
               print(string)
               w.config(text=voltage0)
               w['text'] = voltage0

            if (voltage0==6.5):
               
               print()
               print(voltage0)
               print(string)  
               w.config(text=voltage0)
               w['text'] = voltage0
      
      main()
     
on()
```

Comment: Note that code behind `root.mainloop()` will not be executed until the root window is closed or destroyed.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question. In particular, it is better to add text before the code to explain in more detail what you want to do and what is not working as expected.